# Java applet: actionlistener of button with noname

Tags: java, swing, applet, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a HashMap of JButtons which represents pictures.

`this.nahledy.put(s.getName(), new JButton());`

```
this.nahledy.get(s.getName()).addActionListener();
```

but I don't know how to tell the actionlistener which button has been pressed since the e.getActioncommand() is nothing and the s.getName() is already changed when user presses the button so I can't use it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not perfect but maybe you can use something like this

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
   Set<String> keys = nahledy.keySet();

   for(String key : keys) {
      if(nahledy.get(key).equals(source)) {
         // do something with your button
      }
   }
}
```

This way you can find out the value of s.getName() you used for this button.

Comment: I guess I didn't explained the problem enought. I need to know the key of the button from the HashMap since it's name of a picture and I want to load it when pressed. So the s.getName() is something like "image.gif".

Comment: I am sorry, my bad for not googling enough but I didnt expect there is something like setActionCommand(). Problem solved but thank you for your effort :)